# How to get the <p> in a div Cheerio Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, request, cheerio

I am not able to get the p out of a div (here is the link to the div http://prntscr.com/newlv8)

```
const descriptionHeading = $('div.product-description description-expanded');
const descriptionText = descriptionHeading.find('p');
```

I expect it to set const descriptionText to the description in the picture so when I console.log(descriptionText); it prints out the description shown in the picture.

Answer (score 1):

you have a two class so change like this.Mention class representation `.` instead of space in second class

```
const descriptionHeading = $('div.product-description.description-expanded');
```

Answer (score 0):

$(".product-description p").text()